# How to turn off image scaling

Tags: product-images

I would like to turn off image scaling in the default RWD skin or make it so it does not do any form of image zooming for the product category images. If the browser requires a 280 pixel wide image, then it should be using  a 281 pixel wide image or find a larger one to downscale. Right now, it takes these tiny 210 pixel wide image which features text and zooms in on them making them look aweful.

After reading numerous posts on the Internet, I have yet to find a solution to this specific issue. The only solution I found so far is to make the product category have five columns instead of 4 to make it less likely that this issue will occur. Unfortunately, this is not much of a solution as I find five columns less pretty and more confusing to view than four columns. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue with the RWD skin/theme?

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question.

In the list.phtml file, I changed:
`<?php $_imgSize = 400; ?>`

from 300 number and 210.
`<?php $_imgSize = 281; ?>`

Now images display around 281 pixels wide on 22 inch monitor with no side columns which is good and scales 281 X 281 image down to around 173 X 173 when screen made small. Sure it wastes a little bandwidth but looks much better and doesn't really matter after first load since images cached on client system.